# Bell tower end game

Tags: citadels

If you build a card bell tower, the game can be completed after the 7th turn. Can somebody destroy the bell tower with armory, after he build the seventh card? And if it can be destroyed, is the game over anyway?

Answer (score 3):

According to all the FAQ's I have seen the armory can still be used to destroy the bell tower after the 7th district is build since the card does not disallow it like the warlord does. While the warlord says 8 districts it must be remembered that the bell tower modifies the rules to change winning from 8 to 7 which would also change what is on the warlords cards. However even if you do destroy the bell tower the game would still end as the end game condition is triggered when it is met not at the end of a round.

From the [rule book](http://desktopgames.com.ua/games/3/citadelsrules.pdf).

> When a player builds his eighth district, the game ends after the current round is completed.

This rule does not care if something happens after the victory conditions are met but just that they where. And in this case the conditions where changed from 8 to 7, they where met and then later changed.

Also from the official [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/support/citadels-faq.pdf)

> Q: If the Bell Tower is in play, can the Warlord
>   destroy someone’s seventh district?
>
> A: No. The Bell Tower makes a seven-district city
>   “completed,” and the Warlord cannot destroy districts in a
>   completed city.
>
> Q: How do you handle the endgame scoring bonuses
>   when the Bell Tower has been built?
>
> A: The bonuses are awarded for seven districts instead
>   of eight. If one or more players have seven districts when
>   the Bell Tower is built, they all get the four bonus points
>   for simultaneously meeting the seven district condition.
>   If the Bell Tower is built as someone’s seventh district, he
>   and anyone else with seven districts get four bonus points
>   for simultaneously meeting the endgame condition; any
>   players to subsequently reach seven districts before the
>   round (and the game) ends get two bonus points.

Comment: After the Bell Tower has been destroyed, you still need 8 districts to have a completed city. So end game bonus points for city completion only go to those who have 8 districts.

Comment: Also, major wake up call for me, turns out the Dutch rules translation is awful. For example, it says the warlord can't destroy buildings from cities with 8 districts, and doesn't mention whether or not that city has been completed.

Comment: Actually, the Dutch rules explicitly state that "If the Bell Tower" is removed from the game, the game continues until the 8th district has been built".

Comment: @freekvd The warlord really isn't allowed to destroy districts of completed cities. This is clearly stated in the english rules.

Comment: @Ramiro I'm writing a meta post about how to handle rule differences between countries, with this question as its main example. Fantasy Flight's Citadels and 999 Games' Citadels have entirely different rules at some points. The official Fantasy Flight Citadels FAQ literally contradicts 999 Games' rules.

Comment: @freekvd Does it say if the bell tower is removed after the 7th district has been built and 7 districts where declared as the winning number?

Comment: @JoeW it does not. But even if it did, I believe that this would be overruled by the phrase "the game continues until the 8th district has been built."

Comment: @freekvd Where is that phrase located? In the official English version of the rules it does indicate that once the end game is triggered it can't be prevented from happening. So I am unsure of how removal of the bell tower after end game is triggered would change that.

Comment: I said earlier that those were the rules in the Dutch (and German) rule book.

Comment: @freekvd And I was quoting the rules and link I posted, honestly if you are going to claim a difference in how the rules are worded you should provide the information to show the differences rather then just say they are different. The more I gather it seems like the different languages should be considered different games since some of the rule differences seem pretty big.

Comment: Meta post here: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/rule-translation-differences this comment section is getting unnecessarily long.

Comment: @freekvd I have responded to the meta post and the German bell tower card translated into English via Google translate read the same as the English card so there should be no difference.